# Sitecore 9.1 Upgrade - Lucene to SOLR

Tags: solr, upgrade

I am updating Lucene to SOLR as part of Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.1 upgrade.

I have updated some search configuration like updated field map to:

```
<fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
```

Updated more than 100 fields like below is one example

From:

```
<field fieldName="all_templates" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

To:

```
<field fieldName="all_templates"returnType="stringCollection" />
```

Updated configuration to refer SOLR configuration instead of Lucene

I also removed below configuration and code as I was getting error

> "Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreIndexableItem.set_IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter".

Configuration

```
<IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Foundation.Indexing.Formatters.MyFieldStoreValueFormatter, My.Foundation.Indexing" />
```

Code from Sitecore crawling extension method

```
sitecoreIndexableItem.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter = context.Index.Configuration.IndexFieldStorageValueFormatter;
```

My indexes are building successfully but search functionality is not working.

I am not sure:-

1. If Formatter removal was a right step.
2. If I am missing anything or did something wrong.
3. Is there any explicit code or configuration which is not required with Solr in Sitecore 9.1 (or needs to be changed)

Thanks

Comment: Is this a custom index?

Comment: Hi Chris, Yes, there are many custom indexes.

Comment: Also are you using dynamic fields in your search like `x["fieldName"].Contains("Search word")`

Comment: Yes something similar like AllTemplates.Contains(Id)

Comment: Ok great. Look at your search logs and see what the fields are called in the logs vs what they are called in the actual index. Like `fieldname_s` vs `fieldname_sm`. You can take the ?q=.... and paste it right into your solr website. Sitecore tries to find the right field to search on and in solr it is wrong.

Comment: Search logs are in App_Data/logs/Search.....log if you didn't already know.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yep I am regularly checking search log.. Another point as I have mentioned in my question that I have updated field to <field fieldName="abc" returnType="string" /> from: <field fieldName="abc"  nullValue="NULLVALUE" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" /> so should i retain any configuration in updated one like nullValue="NULLVALUE" or anything else?

Comment: Also what about Formatter as I have mentioned, I have removed that completely.

Comment: I think I sent you a slack message.